# Como consultar do registro mais recente pro menos recente?

Tags: php, sql, data

tenho a seguinte query sql - código abaixo - e gostaria de incrementar nela um "filtro" de insert mais recente para que a consulta fique do insert mais recente pro menos recente.

```
$sql = "
    select 
        ec.id_contrato,
        e.nome_entidade,
        c.valor_total_contrato,
        c.situacao,
        c.data_criacao
    from
        tb_entidade e, tb_entidade_contrato ec, tb_contrato c
    where
        e.id_entidade = ec.id_entidade
        and c.id_contrato = ec.id_contrato
        and ec.id_entidade_tipo = 1
    group by
        id_contrato, nome_entidade;
    ";
```

*tenho uma coluna chamada "data_criacao" com o tipo "datetime NULL [current_timestamp()]", creio que o filtro possa partir daí.

por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Penso que, no final você poderia adicionar o comando

ORDER BY c.data_criacao DESC;

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!